# как организовать правильные связи между таблицами Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Помогите мне правильно создать связи между таблицами! Я добавила фото того, как я это себе представляю, но не уверена, что оно правильное! Идея в том, когда выбираете категорию, вам нужно показать подкатегорию, то если это самый низкий уровень в том смысле, что если вы, например, выбрали смартфон, то она должна показывать все атрибуты, которые для них существуют; если вы выбрали бренд, то он должен отображать все атрибуты, которыми обладают бренды!

Я использую MongoDb Mongoose.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]